# different ways of making 2d vector and list

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

So I have this snippet

```
vector<int> *adj;
adj = new vector<int>[n];
```

and this another common way

```
vector<vector<int> adj(n);
```

can former way of using pointer be used to make 2d array ? And will it work the same way like latter does?

Also when is former way used if in case it can be used to make 2d vectors.

Can I use former way for making 2d list too?

Incase for those of you who are wondering former method is  wrong way of making list it's on geeks for geeks
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/

Comment: Why would you on purpose want to use pointers?  That first code snippet is missing one big piece -- that piece is when to deallocate that vector.  The second snippet takes care of all of those details.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wouldn't, I saw it in someone's codes. Beside, always nice to find new ways of doing things.

Comment: See my edit to the comment.  The first snippet is missing a lot -- it isn't as simple as just calling `new`.  As to `std::list`, what exactly do you mean by a `2d list`?  a vector of `std::list`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nonetheless former seems to work fine. And no 2d list was like...list of list.

Comment: You're missing the point.  The former does not work fine if the proper call to `delete []` is not made at the proper time.  There are thousands of questions on StackOverflow where the poster does the first code, and wonders why Valgrind gives errors, why the destructor crashes, etc.  And to a list of list, why not simply compile it and see if it works `std::list<std::list<int>>`

Comment: as a programmer you are expected to use the most readable and effective way to do things -- use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  doing some half-assed thing with pointers will only come and bite you later.

Comment: @AndersK.   I know this isn't the correct way, but I wish to understand how that way works

Comment: @Mark ok fair enough. the other extreme is to allocate all of it on the heap without using vectors at all

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways to create a multidimensional vectors but I use this method which utilizes struct,

Here is an example for 2X2 table

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct table
{
    std::vector<int> column;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<table> myvec;
    // values of the column for row1
    table t1;
    t1.column = {1,2};
    // Push the first row
    myvec.push_back(t1);
    // values of the column for row2
    table t2;
    t2.column = { 3, 4};
    // push the second row
    myvec.push_back(t2);
    // now let us see whether we've got a 2x2 table
    for(auto row : myvec)
    {
        auto values = row.column; 
        for(auto value : values) std::cout<< value << " ";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
    // Now we will try to get a particular value from the column index of a particular row
    table row = myvec[1]; // 2nd row
    std::cout<<"The value present at 2nd row and 1st column is: "<<row.column[0] <<"\n";
}
```

which gives me,

```
1 2 
3 4 
The value present at 2nd row and 1st column is: 3
```

You can easily change it to different dimensions.

Note: I have posted this answer to my knowledge if it is wrong somebody correct me. Thank you

Comment: The same method is applicable to std::list too!

Comment: okay everyone, really good job. But in my post I wanna understand how my first method works and where it works.